# how to create small task bar in uitableviewcell ios xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

how to create small task bar  (Reply, Copy, Forword and Delete) in uitableviewcell like whatsapp when the message on press? 
[image]

Comment: UIMenuController is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

"UIMenuController" with "menuItems:" will be useful for your custom Actions.

Apple Documentation Link : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller

Answer (score 0):

thank Ios Developer for your direction.. i already use "UIMenuController", but this menu is not shown.

my code:

```
    [Export("LongPressMethod:")]
    public void LongPressMethod(UILongPressGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
        {
            var menuController = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;
            var copyMenuItem = new UIMenuItem("copy", new ObjCRuntime.Selector("CopyRow"));
            var pasteMenuItem = new UIMenuItem("paste", new ObjCRuntime.Selector("PasteRow"));
            var location = gestureRecognizer.LocationInView(bc);
            bc.BecomeFirstResponder();
            menuController.MenuItems = new[] { copyMenuItem, pasteMenuItem };
            menuController.SetTargetRect(new CGRect(location.X, location.Y, 100, 100), bc);
            menuController.SetMenuVisible(true, true);

        }
    }

    [Export("CopyRow:")]
    void Row(UIMenuController controller)
    {
        // do something
    }

    [Export("PasteRow:")]
    void PasteRow(UIMenuController controller)
    {
        // do something
    }
```